# How to create a Gridview with Template fields and I want to display the empty gridview on execution

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to create a Gridview with Template Fields and I wanted to set the cells to null and I want to Display them in the page. Bu I succeeded in creating the Template fields but initializing the cells to null is not working. Pls help me with this. Thank you.

This is the GridView HTML code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="grdReqDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesig" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Skill Set">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSkillSet" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Experience">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Num of Candidates">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And the Code behind:

```
        grdReqDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "";
        grdReqDetails.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text = "";
        grdReqDetails.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text = "";
        grdReqDetails.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text = "";
        grdReqDetails.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text = "";
```

Comment: I tried but I didnt get a way to set the initial values of the cell to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void DisGridBind()
    {

        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow Dr;
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col2");
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col3");
        Dt.Columns.Add("Col4");
        Dr = Dt.NewRow();
        Dt.Rows.Add(Dr);
        gv_discpoint.DataSource = Dt;
        gv_discpoint.DataBind();
      }
```

Comment: I already have the Rows as Template field but I want those rows to get displayed.

Comment: This is a way to add empty row in gridview

Answer (score 0):

For initial empty GridView, you should use **EmptyDataTemplate** like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdReqDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">             
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="S.No"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Designation"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesig" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Skill Set"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSkillSet" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Experience"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Num of Candidates"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesig" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Skill Set">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSkillSet" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Experience">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Num of Candidates">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```